# make custom action when try to remove row MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm using 3-rd side library 'datatables' in my project to manage products table. When user click delete button on client, I want selected product recieve delete flag (bit column in the products table), but this library just delete row. Can I prevent delete action and set my own action (by trigger for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with "DataTables" library. Change the TYPE of Remove attribute of datatable Editor to "PUT" instead of "DELETE". There in PUT action you can update delete flag.